# MbedTls: Writing public-key in DER-format (mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_der) works, but writing same key in PEM (mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_pem) fails?

Tags: c, cryptography, embedded, mbedtls

I'm trying to write out a public key created using MbedTls in a c-programm. This works when using the function to write out DER-keys as it returns the number of bytes written (91) and the key in pubKeyBufferDer, but trying to write out the same key in PEM-format instead returns an error.
The functions parameters are almost identical, so I don't understand what could be/cause the error?

the two functions:

```
int numBytesWritten = mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_der(&keyContainerTest, pubKeyBufferDer, sizeof(pubKeyBufferDer));     //working //returns 91 as return-value and the key in pubKeyBufferDer  
int writePubkeyPemRtn = mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_pem(&keyContainerTest, pubKeyBufferPem, sizeof(pubKeyBufferPem));      //not working //returns -42 (int) or 4294967254/0xFFFFFFD6 (uint) and doesn't write anything to pubKeyBufferPem
```

full code:

```
int main() {

    uint8_t inputKeyMaterialTest[32];
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(inputKeyMaterialTest); i++) {
        inputKeyMaterialTest[i] = 0x7;  //just as an example
    }
    uint8_t outputKeyMaterialTest[32];
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(outputKeyMaterialTest); i++) {
        outputKeyMaterialTest[i] = 0;
    }
    
    int hkdfRtn = mbedtls_hkdf(mbedtls_md_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256), NULL, 0, inputKeyMaterialTest, sizeof(inputKeyMaterialTest), NULL, 0, outputKeyMaterialTest, sizeof(inputKeyMaterialTest));                    
    
    mbedtls_hmac_drbg_context hmacDrbgCtxTest;
    mbedtls_hmac_drbg_init(&hmacDrbgCtxTest);
    int hmacDrbgSeedBufRtn = mbedtls_hmac_drbg_seed_buf(&hmacDrbgCtxTest, mbedtls_md_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256), outputKeyMaterialTest, sizeof(outputKeyMaterialTest));
    
    mbedtls_pk_context keyContainerTest;
    mbedtls_pk_init(&keyContainerTest);
    int pkSetupRtn = mbedtls_pk_setup(&keyContainerTest, mbedtls_pk_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_PK_ECKEY));
    
    mbedtls_ecp_keypair_init(mbedtls_pk_ec(* (mbedtls_pk_context*) &keyContainerTest));
    int genKeyRtn = mbedtls_ecp_gen_key(MBEDTLS_ECP_DP_SECP256R1, mbedtls_pk_ec(* (mbedtls_pk_context*) &keyContainerTest), &mbedtls_hmac_drbg_random, &hmacDrbgCtxTest);
    
    uint8_t pubKeyBufferDer[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pubKeyBufferDer); i++){
        pubKeyBufferDer[i] = 0;
    }
    int numBytesWritten = mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_der(&keyContainerTest, pubKeyBufferDer, sizeof(pubKeyBufferDer));     //works //returns 91 as return-value and the key in pubKeyBufferDer 

    uint8_t pubKeyBufferPem[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pubKeyBufferPem); i++){
        pubKeyBufferPem[i] = 0;
    }
    int writePubkeyPemRtn = mbedtls_pk_write_pubkey_pem(&keyContainerTest, pubKeyBufferPem, sizeof(pubKeyBufferPem));      //not working //returns -42 (int) or 4294967254 (uint) and doesn't write anything to pubKeyBufferPem

return 0;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: PEM encoded data is larger than DER encoded data. Check whether the buffer is large enough in the PEM case (128 bytes is probably too small, even for an EC key).